# AngularJS <auto-complete> directive inside the <tags-input> doesn't work in chrome browser

Tags: html, angularjs

I am trying to create a simple tags-input field in AngularJS, using ngTagsInput directive. I have some tag names in tags.json, which I want to be displayed as suggestions while entering the tag names in input field, for which I am trying to use auto-complete directive, inside tags-input.

Here is the index.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://mbenford.github.io/ngTagsInput/css/ng-tags-input.min.css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.2/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://mbenford.github.io/ngTagsInput/js/ng-tags-input.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ngTagsInput']);

      app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
        $scope.tags = [
          { text: 'Tag1' },
          { text: 'Tag2' },
          { text: 'Tag3' }
        ];

        $scope.loadTags = function(query) {
          return $http.get('tags.json');
        };
      });
    </script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <tags-input ng-model="tags" add-on-paste="true">
      <auto-complete source="loadTags($query)"></auto-complete>
    </tags-input>
    <p>Model: {{tags}}</p>
  </body>

</html>
```

Here is the tags.json :

```
[
  { "text": "Tag1" },
  { "text": "Tag2" },
  { "text": "Tag3" },
  { "text": "Tag4" },
  { "text": "Tag5" },
  { "text": "Tag6" },
  { "text": "Tag7" },
  { "text": "Tag8" },
  { "text": "Tag9" },
  { "text": "Tag10" }
]
```

The code works fine in firefox and displays the suggestions in a dropdown manner once you type 'Tag' in the input field. However in chrome it does not display the suggestions, but the rest of the things work fine.

Here is the screenshot of the app in chrome:
[image]

Any idea how to accomplish this in chrome?

Comment: can you show a demo with above mentioned issue?

Comment: i've added a screenshot of the app in chrome

Comment: in firefox when I click on the print-screen button, the dropdown goes away, so it looks the same as chrome

Comment: m not sure if it has something to do with my chrome settings or else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So yea, after digging a little, I figured out that chrome has some security issues which doesn't allow files to be loaded from the local machine, in this case `tags.json`.
Solution: You can host the file on some server or even on WAMP, should work fine.